# Is there any chance that the next version of C++ will have Microsoft's property extension?

Tags: c++

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/es7h5kch.aspx

This feature looks pretty sweet. This would be great because you wouldn't need getters any more. You could make member variables public; later, if you change your mind, you can turn them into property.

Is this something that the standard committee has considered? Is this something they would likely accept or reject? Does this already exist and I just don't know about it yet?

Comment: This isn't something anyone outside the C++ standards body can answer.

Comment: Boy, I hope not.

Comment: This might possibly help: [MS Specific, __declspec, property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhfk0thd.aspx)

Comment: This is the sort of thing that many development environments will auto-generate for you, so even if it was seen as generally useful, there would be no great pressure to make it a part of the language.

Comment: @millimoose:  A number of whom post on SO.

Comment: I have not seen any proposal in that direction (and I personally don't find that to be such a *sweet* feature).

Comment: @JohnDibling I could invent a lengthier rationale for why this doesn't seem like a good fit for SO regardless of that.

Comment: Voted to reopen.  It is clearly on-topic for SO.

Comment: @millimoose: The papers and proposals for each meeting of the committee are publicly available, so this is not just for people in the committee (and there are a few SO users that are members also)

Comment: @millimoose:  Go ahead, because from my point of view your original rationale is pretty weak.

Comment: @JohnDibling As I see it there are four possible outcomes. "It's been considered and accepted" but even a cursory search would've revealed a blog post of someone describing the upcoming cool stuff and more likely than not the question wouldn't have been asked. "It's been considered and rejected" which is the only conclusive answer remaining. And "it's being considered with no conclusion" and "no such proposal has been submitted", neither of which actually answers the question "What are the chances?" since the future is unknowable.

Comment: @JohnDibling And even in the case that a C++ committee member does chip in, whose a priori likelihood I can't determine, his answer wouldn't carry much weight. It'd amount to "based on the pros and cons that popped into my head over the course of ~30 minutes I'd vote no", which I don't see as a good approximation of the actual process a language feature proposal goes through.

Comment: @JohnDibling "Boy, I hope not." - Why? Everything which can save us from writing some boilerplate code (in this case getters and setters) are valuable IMHO.

Comment: @millimoose:  So what?  Almost every question asked on SO  has a finite set of correct answers, could be answered by a Google search or further study, and evokes the opinions of those answering.  None of that makes questions off-topic here.  Some people vote to close questions which present an idea or paradigm that they don't *like*, but that's also not a valid reason to close a question.  The fact that **I** don't like the prospect of "property extensions" being added to the Standard is not reason enough for me to vote to close.

Comment: @CsabaToth:  We're getting off-topic here, but in short because I'm afraid their excessive use would promulgate poorly-designed code.  To wit, getters/setters where just a public member would be more appropriate.  For much the same reason, I'm not a big fan of `auto`.  More to the point, gratuitous use of `auto`.

Comment: @JohnDibling What you described is merely the reason why we the close vote reasons only come with a brief summary. SO moderation is the result of a dynamic consensus, not of lawyering around the letter of the rules. Just because *every* question has *some* space for expressing one's opinion in an answer doesn't mean we shouldn't try to weed out opinion polls, and my two cents on the issue were that given the nature and history of the C++ language evolution process, this question is effectively an opinion poll.

Comment: @JohnDibling You've actually just illustrated my point too. If whenever it is in the past someone had asked "What are the chances of C++ getting something like C#'s `var`?" (i.e. `auto`), and you were a member of the committee and chanced upon the question, you'd have answered "I don't think so." if no such proposal was under discussion at the moment to give you an idea of the prevailing sentiment. IIRC this happened with C++11, which grew some features that a library could've provided, when the predominant groupthink before that was "only add to the language what *must* be a language feature"

Comment: @millimoose: That is not 100% how things work. I know a couple of people in the committee, and after the meetings the proposals are categorized in: not yet considered, considered and accepted, considered and definitely rejected, for the rest they usually have a good feeling of how the committee feels, ranging from very unlikely to be accepted to has high chances of acceptance if this or that issues are addressed. On the particular case of `auto`, it was considered interesting, but was not accepted. It took a few rounds of fixing issues and defining missing behavior, but chances were high.

Comment: [...] of course, if you asked a couple of years ago about concepts, chances of that being accepted were very high, until some additional concerns were raised and were deemed important enough to rewrite *many* parts of the standard to surgically remove concepts from the working draft.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Right, so my assumption of how the standardisation process works was off the mark. I was mostly extrapolating from what I know of the JCP or web standards and the longish time between C++ versions, and thought the lifecycle of a proposal was long, clumsy, possibly involving tabling and rethinking some ideas more than once. As in I'm not saying that a random sampling of one-two individual committee members carries *no* value, I just thought it wasn't much.

Comment: @millimoose: As an example, N3525 was proposed on behalf of my company (it proposes a mechanism for polymorphic memory allocation for standarization, we already use that mechanism internally), and it has not been accepted yet, but at the end of last meeting the consensus was that the paper had been *well received*. Does that mean that it will be accepted, no. But it means that the chances for acceptance are there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is old.  Borland added it first, back in 90s, with C++ Builder if I'm not mistaken.  Microsoft followed suit, they were highly competitive back then.  COM Automation was a pretty major motivator.

Given that this had three C++ language versions to stew, along with the controversy around it,  the odds that this will be considered for a future revision are about zilch.

Properties have their use but they cause considerable implementation difficulties.  Passing a property by reference for example is a very difficult problem to solve.  The callee would need to know that an accessor needs to be called, instead of just dereferencing a pointer, and would need to know whether a getter or setter even exists.  The only practical solution is to just forbid it, not exactly attractive in C++.  Additional problems add up when you start to support default properties, very hard to pass up, introducing syntax ambiguity.

Comment: I'm probably going off on a limb here, but I seem to recall Common Lisp had some notion of first-class lvalues. ("place forms" or some such.) Prior art in compiling those might help in addressing those difficulties, although I suppose in Lisps it was more acceptable to lose performance to support these edge cases.

Comment: Taking the proxy object by reference is a practical solution too, as long as you're passing it to a generic algorithm (templated and able to accept a proxy object).  Which is the C++ way of doing things anyway.

Answer (score 8):

Since this is already possible in standard-compliant C++ using a library-only approach (proxy objects), it's unlikely to see language changes and new keywords.  Unlike lambdas (for instance), the possible syntactic sugar here isn't all that sweet (doesn't change the level of abstraction much).

BTW, changing fields (wrapperless member variables) into properties is always a breaking change, because you can form pointers and references to fields and read/write them directly.  With a property, you'd need a wrapper in order to ensure that the getters and setters are used.

The reason for the Microsoft extension is that it doesn't simply provide properties (interception of read and write to getter and setter functions) in C++ code.  It generates .NET metadata or WinRT metadata (in C++/CLI and C++/CX, respectively) which is used by reflection.  Standard C++ doesn't have reflection or metadata.

Also note that C++ developers tend not to use the proxy object pattern very much, which indicates to the committee that there isn't much demand for a "cleaner" syntactic sugar, either.

Comment: This answer is also excellent; unfortunately, I can only mark one answer as correct :'(